# $y'' + y' = \frac 43x - 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was able to get the solution to $y'' + y' = \frac 43x - 1$ by using variation of parameters. I got $y = \frac 23 x^2 - \frac 73 x+c_1+c_2e^{-x}.$ But I wanted to know how to solve this using undetermined coefficients since that method is easier.

The characteristic polynomial is $r^2+r=r(r+1)=0$ which has roots $r=0,-1$ so $y_c = c_1+c_2 e^{-x}.$ What I learned is that if the "forcing function" ($\frac 43x -1$ in this problem) shares a term that is $x^k$ times a term in $y_c,$ where k is a nonnegative integer, then $y_p$ will contain a term that is $x^{k+1}$ times the shared term. Since $y_c$ and the forcing function have the term "1" in common, I thought this meant that $y_p$ would contain a term $x^{0+1}*1=x.$ So $y_p$ would have the form $Ax+B.$ Since B is accounted for in $y_c$, I tried to use $y_p=Ax.$

This gave me the wrong answer, which made me think I need to try a solution of the form $y_p=Ax^2+Bx.$ However, I don't know where the $x^2$ term comes from! If this is the right form, can someone explain where the quadratic term comes from? If I'm wrong, please correct me. Also, sorry if there are any typos. Thank you. :)

Comment: Try $$y_p(x) = x( a + b x)$$ Since you already have a constant in the ODE on the RHS, the additional $x$ tries to account for that. Substitute this into the ODE and equate like terms to find $a = -\dfrac{7}{3}$ and $b = \dfrac{2}{3}$. There are some nice UC strategies at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx.

Comment: @Moo Thanks for your comment and the link. But I couldn't find any similar examples to this problem on that webpage. Also, the table on the webpage says that when the forcing function is an nth degree polynomial, you should guess $y_p$ to be $A_{n}x^n+A_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+A_0$ which goes against what is needed in this problem. So this must be a special case.

Comment: Why not substitute $v=y'$ and then solve it as a first order linear ODE using an integrating factor?

Comment: @Aladris: I think you should spend more time going through Examples 9 and 10 in detail - those are the important concepts for your type of problem.

Comment: @projectilemotion Good suggestion. And thanks to everyone for the comments. Looks like underdetermined coefficients isn't the best method to solve this DE.

Answer (score 2):

I like to think of it like this:

If you assume that $y$ is a solution to your differential equation, and differentiate both sides of your equation, you will get
$$
y''''+y'''=((4/3)x-1)''=0.
$$
Thus, $y$ has to be a solution to the *homogeneous* differential equation $y''''-y'''=0$. This differential equation has characteristic equation $\lambda^4-\lambda^3=0$. You see that you have a root $\lambda=0$ of multiplicity $3$ and a root $\lambda=1$ of multiplicity $1$. Hence
$$
y(x)=(a+bx+cx^2)e^{0x}+de^{x}=a+bx+cx^2+de^x.
$$
I think you recognize the terms $a$ and $de^x$ from your $y_c$. The other parts must be your particular solution. Hence, the correct ansatz is
$$
y_p(x)=bx+cx^2.
$$
Now just insert and differentiate, to find $b$ and $c$.

Comment: This is the annihilator method, right? Thank you for sharing this. This gives a lot of intuition to the quadratic term in $y_p.$

Comment: I did not know it had a name, but thanks. It explains why one should multiply the natural ansatz with $x$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no $y$-term on the LHS. Hence the term with the smallest degree of $x-$ polynomial on the LHS is $y'$. In this case you should let $y' = Ax+B$ instead. This is the same as claiming that $y$ is a quadratic polynomial in $x$.

Then as you claimed the constant term is absorbed by the solution to the homogeneous counterpart. So we let $y=Dx^2 + Ex $